# A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.workers$actionfacade See the Console for details

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

When I try build Android application. I got some error about R8.
I used to be able to build successfully, but at some point I started getting errors.

[image]

> Configure project :launcher
> WARNING: The option 'android.enableR8' is deprecated and should not be used anymore.

I googled android.enableR8 and it only worked for people developing apps in Android Studio.

My project currently uses PUN 2 to enable multiplayer, and Firebase for the database.

---

Also, the error continues below;

> 注意：D:\UnityProjects(ProjectName)\Temp\gradleOut\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\unity3d\player\UnityPlayerActivity.javaは非推奨のAPIを使用またはオーバーライドしています。
> 注意:詳細は、-Xlint:deprecationオプションを指定して再コンパイルしてください。

It says UnityPlayerActivity.java uses a deprecated API, and check details by using -Xlint:deprecation option.

I don't know what -Xlint:deprecation is, and I don't remember changing the Unity Playern settings.

Is this a Unity bug? Or is it a bug in IL2CPP?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the cause yet, and I haven't solved it fundamentally, but I found that the problem was in Firebase.

I deleted all the Firebase related folders and the build worked.